# Ruby on Rails path understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update an existing title and a description . My items are called todo, and the database is todos(since I generate with the generate commant) . 
The code that i have is 
edit.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for :session, url: todos_path(@todo), method: :patch do |f|  %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <br />


  <%= f.submit "Create" %>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
  get "/todos", to: "todos#index"
  get "/todos/new", to: "todos#new"
  post "/todos", to: "todos#create"
  delete "/todos/delete" , to: "todos#delete"
  get "/todos/three", to: "todos#three"
  post "/todos/edit", to: "todos#edit"
  patch "/todos/edit", to: "todos#update" 

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'todos#index'
```

and finally the controller:

```
  def edit
    @todo = Todo.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    todo = Todo.find_by_id(params[:session][:id])
    todo.update(:description,params[:session][:description])
  end
```

My problem is : I come from the index page with an ID and the edit function display me the item that I want, then I want to update the title and description field and to hit the f.submit button to update it. My issue is that the parameters don't come, I get todos.2 (which I guess it's the size of that :session hash ?).
   I do not with to use <%= button_to %> since I saw it is not needed in all tutorials .
   My question is where is my mistake, why don't the parameters come ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change routes to this:

```
patch "/todos/edit/:id", to: "todos#update", as: :update_todo
```

then form:

```
<%= form_for :session, url: update_todo_path(id: @todo.id), method: :patch do |f|  %>
```

and then controller:

```
def update
  todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  todo.update_attributes(params[:session].slice(:description))
end
```

However, I'd recommend you to stick with the convention instead of writing and defining your own named routes for such purposes.

Comment: ,yes, I do plan to stick with the convention . However to understand how they really work I consider I have to make my own at first(i clearly am a beginner). I get an error with your code undefined local variable or method update_todo

Comment: @LucianTarna :  Sorry, that was a typo. Missing `:` in `update_todo`. Corrected now, it should work.

Comment: Yep, i saw . The problem is now that it won't get the todo.update_attributes(params[:session].slice(:description)) . ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError .

Comment: AA i got it, Had to make this def session_params
     params.require(:session).permit(:title,:description)
  end

Answer (score 2):

Change in routes:

```
patch   "/todos/:id", to: "todos#update", as: "update_todo"
```

In form:

```
<%= form_for @todo, url: update_todo_path(@todo), method: :patch, do |f| %>
```

In controller:

```
def update
  @todo.update(params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :description))
  @todo.save
end
```

If you want to know all existing routes, you may use:

```
$ rake routes
```

It will show table like

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
       root GET    /                               posts#index
    sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)              users#new
```

where prefix will be you path url like 'sign_up' it is "sign_up_path" in controller/views.